# Sightstone vs Yellow-Trinket on Lee Sin

Tags: league-of-legends

With patch 5.3 Riot introduced a change to the yellow trinket -> Now it stores up to two charges while refreshing them by 1 every 60 seconds.

As a Lee Sin player, I always tended to buy a sighstone (even though at times I just went straight for the wards to get pure combat stats instead of the sightstone).
Now with the new yellow trinket, I wanted to ask if you guys think if it is still worth to get sightstone?

Comment: Wards win games.

Comment: I vote to reopen this question since this is a problem commonly faced by the league community and it's objectively answerable by an experienced league player.

Comment: It's also still primarily opinion-based.

Comment: If Toby rewords this to be more about the benefits of one item over another, then it will be objectively answerable. Unfortunately @Jutschge as it currently stands it is still very opionion-based

Answer (score 5):

It's still very viable to get a sighstone (at least the blue version). The problem with the trinket upgrade is that you need level 9 to purchase it. And even after that you can wardjump only once or twice every 60 seconds.

What makes Sightstone so powerful on lee is the fact that you basically have 4 free flashes withing 60 seconds while it also provides you with extra HP which is extremely strong during early game.

Unless you are super fed it's still better to go for a sightstone for extra mobility and utility. It makes ganking and counterjungling a lot easier and safer. If you are super fed however you can rush your Hydra and just instakill everything during early and midgame while also buying some single wards but the trinket upgrade itself isn't a huge gamechanger for Lee.

You should still buy it though if you have 250 gold left and you don't know what else to buy since it provides good objective control.

Comment: If you have a sightstone you might as well change your yellow trinket for a red trinket